# Mac Powerlevel10k change icon for os identifier

Tags: macos, shell, zsh

I have installed Powerlevel10k on my Macbook Pro (m1). I have changed the "os identifier" icon since having the Apple icon provides little value. Instead I would simply like to have fun with this setting and personlize it.

I have uncommented the following line in .p10k.zsh, in the `##[ os_icon: os identifier ]##` section:

`typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_OS_ICON_CONTENT_EXPANSION='⭐'`

Now I get the star in my prompt instead of the Apple icon, which is an improvement that I would take as-is, but I would like to go further.

I am unfamiliar with this syntax of how the star is reprsented as an actual icon in the code in my editor.  What is controlling this?

How can I change this icon from the star, to say, a 4-leaf clover, or a country flag, or some other icon?

Comment: Depends on what subset of unicode your font provides. Note that questions about using and customizing your shell _as an end-user_, as opposed to development-specific questions, are better suited to [unix.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The star is an emoji. You can use whatever string you want.

```
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_OS_ICON_CONTENT_EXPANSION=''
```

```
typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_OS_ICON_CONTENT_EXPANSION=''
```